# What is the difference between Antenna gain and Channel gain?

Tags: rf, antenna, communication, wireless, digital-communications

I have a fairly simple question that I've written in the title but just writing this body to meet stack's 'quality standards'

What is the difference between Antenna gain and Channel gain?

Comment: Answer: Why must the antenna BW be greater than the Channel BW. e.g. 6 kHz channel at 928 MHz ISM band

Comment: What antenna? What channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

antenna gain measures how focussed the beam of an antenna is.

channel gain measure how much power is lost before the signal reaches the antenna.